# Get the Sum of a count with group by in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to present the data as a sum on group by basis and the expected output is something like

```
  Windows-10  yyy 
  Windows-8   xxx
  Windows-7   abc
```

In the table `LOGINHISTORYTABLE`, I have a column `useragent` that stores the value of OS and browser in a special format like

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/8.0; 

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36   etc
```

So my plan is that remove all space in this column so values becomes

```
Mozilla/4.0(compatible;MSIE7.0;WindowsNT10.0;WOW64;Trident/8.0;
Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.3;Trident/7.0;Touch;MAARJS;rv:11.0)likeGecko  etc
```

And assume if the column contains WindowsNT10.0 I count it as a Windows 10 instance

If WindowsNT6.3 is present, I count it as a Windows 8 instance etc

So I am able to find the count with this query:

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(d.UserAgent) as countname,
        Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', ' ') as name
    FROM 
        LOGINHISTORYTABLE as d  
    WHERE 
        d.CreatedDate > '2017-02-08' 
        AND d.CreatedDate < '2017-02-09' 
        AND (Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT10.0%'
        OR Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT6.3%')
    GROUP BY 
        d.UserAgent
```

From this now I want to find SUM for each group

I tried

```
    SELECT SUM(countname) as TotalCount , 'Windows 10' as OS
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(d.UserAgent) as countname,
            Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', ' ') as name
        FROM LOGINHISTORYTABLE as d  
        WHERE d.CreatedDate>  '2017-02-08' AND d.CreatedDate < '2017-02-09' AND 
           (Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT10.0%'
           OR 
           Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT6.3%')
        GROUP BY d.UserAgent
    )a
```

But this returns overall sum only . How can i make this sum as group by and if possible how can i use the custom labels for each group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
WITH TranslatedOS_CTE AS (
SELECT  UserAgent,CreatedDate,
        case when UserAgent like '%NT 6.3%' then 'Windows8'
        when UserAgent like '%Windows NT 10.0%' then 'Windows10'
        else UserAgent
        end as OS        
        FROM LOGINHISTORYTABLE 
)

Select Count(0), [OS] from TranslatedOS_CTE
WHERE CreatedDate>  '2017-02-08' AND CreatedDate < '2017-02-09'
group by OS
```

Comment: Can we make the Case section in the first place to some sort of aliased column and use that aliased column in the end for group by

Comment: I'd make it a Scalar Valued UDF

Comment: You could use a common table expression to do the case operation and set up the data you need to summarize.

Comment: You could also put your mappings into a separate table and make it very easy to maintain.  join onto mapping table using something like left outer join MappingTable mt on useragent like '%' + mt.Map + '%'

Comment: @MikeMiller I feel CTE is more useful in my case due to the limitation of my db structure . Since the database is updated every night [ restore to latest pro version ] and i am running this query on analytics module. How about perfomance CTE / UDF / left join using an extra table

Answer (score 1):

you should group the name in the external query, but first you should build case or regex that will replace the UserAgent to OS

```
 SELECT SUM(countname) as TotalCount , 
        name
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(d.UserAgent) as countname,
            Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', ' ') as name
        FROM LOGINHISTORYTABLE as d  
        WHERE d.CreatedDate>  '2017-02-08' AND d.CreatedDate < '2017-02-09' AND 
           (Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT10.0%'
           OR 
           Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT6.3%')
        GROUP BY d.UserAgent
    )a
group by name
```

Comment: Yes thats what i am missing [ build case to convert userAgent to OS] ANy idea how can i do that without RegX

Comment: . I guess @mat suggested the same

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
SELECT name as OS,SUM(countname) as TotalCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(d.UserAgent) as countname,
            Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', ' ') as name
        FROM LOGINHISTORYTABLE as d  
        WHERE d.CreatedDate>  '2017-02-08' AND d.CreatedDate < '2017-02-09' AND 
           (Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT10.0%'
           OR 
           Replace(d.UserAgent, ' ', '') like '%WindowsNT6.3%')
        GROUP BY d.UserAgent
    )a
    GROUP BY name
```